# Convert integer list to a string

Tags: f#

I am trying to achieve the following. Input is list [8;9;4;5;7] and output should be 
"8,9,4,5,7,"  Note the "," in the output

I tried the following

```
let rec ConvertToString list =
   match list with
   | head :: tail -> head.ToString() + ConvertToString tail
   | [] -> ""

let op= [8;9;4;5;7] |> ConvertToString
```

But the output which i get is val me : string = "89457"

Can anyone kindly suggest how to get get the "," in the output. The function should be generic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the comma between the head and the converted tail, and need another case to convert the last element so you don't add a separating comma.

```
let rec ConvertToString list =
   match list with
   | [l] -> l.ToString()
   | head :: tail -> head.ToString() + "," + ConvertToString tail
   | [] -> ""
```

Note you can also define your function using `String.concat`:

```
let ConvertToString l = l |> List.map (fun i -> i.ToString()) |> String.concat ","
```

or `String.Join`:

```
let ConvertToString (l: 'a seq) = System.String.Join(",", l)
```

If you only want to allow `ConvertToString` to take `int list` arguments, you can specify the type of the input argument explicitly:

```
let ConvertToString (l : int list) = ...
```

Comment: Currently ConvertString is val ConvertToString : list:'a list -> string. How to make it val ConvertToString :  list<int> -> string so that it only accepts integers lists as input

Comment: @user2898331 change the list parameter to specify the type: (list: int list)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a nice version for integer lists:

```
let convertToString = List.map (sprintf "%i") >> String.concat ","
```

or if you want a generic version:

```
let convertToString l = l |> List.map (sprintf "%A") |> String.concat ","
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do this:

```
let ConvertToString (l: int list) =
match l with
| [] -> ""
| h :: t -> List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + "," + x.ToString()) (h.ToString()) t
```